# Substituting the next character from a stream of characters in a while loop

Tags: c

I'm supposed to design a program that count the number of words, so this is part of my code

```
 while ((c=getc(file)) != EOF)

   { if ((isspace(c) || c == '\f' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == '\v')) { ++word; } }
```

The logic of my code should first look at the first character if it was non-space, then it should look at the following if it was space then it should count one word

However, I know how to substitute the current character (in my code) but I don't know how to substitute the following character?

Basically, I want to write my code in this logic form (c+ is the character that follows c)

```
while ((c=getc(file)) != EOF)
  { if ( c is non-space) 
     { if (c+ is space)
        { word++ } 
            } 
          }
```

Comment: Run in debug and check the value `if ((isspace(c) || c == '\f' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == '\v'))` and it will solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks Vativch for your response, but I a ctually don't have any problem with this line I only have a problem with writing the code in my logic, I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
prevC = ' ';
while ((c=getc(file)) != EOF)
{ 
    if ((prevC != ' ') &&
    (isspace(c) || c == '\f' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == '\v')) 
    { 
    ++word;
    } 
    prevC = c;
}
```

You need to maintain previous character that was read and compare it in the next iteration